# QGraphicsScene растягивание мышью элемента QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt

Как мне в `QGraphicsScene` растягивать, ну например, `QGraphicsEllipseItem` мышью, как в Paint'е при выделении? Скиньте мне исходный код или проект Qt Creator. У меня Qt5.

**обновление**

Вот мелкий код там:

```
QGraphicEllipseItem *ellipse;
void FigureEditor::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{

}
void FigureEditor::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{

}
```

Что туда надо добавить?

И, да. Желательно, чтобы менялся курсор при растягивании элемента мышью.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, Ваши наработки (краткие примеры исходных кодов), иначе Ваш вопрос могут закрыть.

Answer (score 2):

у вас в каждом событии есть переменная `event`, у нее есть `x()`, `y()` следовательно знаете координаты начала и конца. посмотрите на примеры от Qt (расположены в `Qt\Examples\Qt-5.5\widgets\graphicsview\`). Скорее всего именно `elasticnodes` вам нужен для примера.

Comment: Это у вас часть URL сайта с документацией или путь к файлу?

Comment: это путь где у вас установлен Qt, например c:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.5\ - там очень много различных и полезных примеров

Comment: ага, понял. Не знал, как отформатировать.

Answer (score 1):

Для изменения курсора вызывайте `QApplication::setOverrideCursor(...)` в обработчике события mousePressEvent, и соответственно `QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor()` в mouseReleaseEvent. По событию mouseMove при нажатой кнопке мыши применяйте к итему функции scale и transform.